# NodeJS / ExpressJS check valid token parameter before routing

Tags: node.js, express, parameters

I have the following app code:

(app.js)

```
var express = require('express')
  , app = express()
  , port = process.env.PORT || 8082

app.use(require('./controllers'))

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.send('Test')
  next()
})

app.listen(port, function() {
  console.log('Listening on port ' + port)
})
```

and two controllers:

(index.js)

```
var express = require('express')
  , router = express.Router()

router.use('/projects', require('./projects'))

module.exports = router
```

(projects.js)

```
var express = require('express')
  , router = express.Router()

router.get('/:id', function(req, res, next) {
  res.json({project: req.params.id})
})

module.exports = router
```

This works but now I have to check my url for a valid token.
My url looks like http://server/api/projects?token=abc or http://server/api/projects/:id?token=abc
If the token is not valid no projects (or other controllers) should be load / shown.
What is the best way to handle this and where (in app.js or controllers/index.js)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a middleware.

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    if (checkToken(req.query.token) {
        return next();
    }

    res.status(403).end("invalid token");
});
app.use(require('./controllers'))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this validation inside your `route` function or you can use a [middleware](http://expressjs.com/guide/using-middleware.html) that validates the `param` and then do some logic.

```
var express = require('express')
   , router = express.Router()

function validate(req,res,next) {
  if(req.params.id) // some logic
  else other stuff

  next();
}

router.get('/:id', validate, function(req, res, next) {
  res.json({project: req.params.id})
})

module.exports = router
```